# How to search for a word in a text file and if found print out the entire line

Tags: c++, io, string-matching

My program needs to search for a word in a text file, and if it finds that word, to print out/display the entire line. Example:

```
employee   name    date joined    position       project        annual salary
tom jones           1/13/2011     accountant    pricing         55000
Susan lee           2/5/2007      Manager       policy          70000
```

User enters a search word:

> accountant

Program searches text for `accountant`. When it finds it, it returns the following:

```
employee   name    date joined    position       project        annual salary
tom jones           1/13/2011     accountant    pricing         55000
```

This is the code I came up with but it doesn't work.

```
void KeyWord(ifstream &FileSearch)
{
     string letters;
     int position =-1;
     string line;
     ifstream readSearch;
     cout<<"enter search word ";
     cin>>letters;
     "\n";
     FileSearch.open("employee");
     if(FileSearch.is_open())
     { 
         while(getline(FileSearch, line))
         {
             FileSearch>>line;
             cout<<line<<endl;
             position=line.find(letters,position+1);
             if(position==string::npos);
             if(FileSearch.eof())
                 break;

             cout<<line<<endl;
         }

     }
     cout<<"Cant find"<<letters<<endl;
 }
```

Answer (score 14):

Easy answer:

```
void Keyword(ifstream & stream, string token) {
    string line;
    while (getline(stream, line)) {
        if (line.find(token) != string::npos) {
            cout << line << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << token << " not found" << endl;
}
```

In general, avoid mixing `<<` and `getline` together when reading from a `stream` as it causes strange issues with line endings.

Comment: thanks I will try this right now..and repost the results, or quesitons.. I'm guessing where you have the word token..Im going to replace with letters.. where i get input from user..?

Comment: updated since I just noticed a bug. The if statement should have a != string::npos. And yeah just replace the string token with whatever you are looking for (accountant in your example)

Comment: Perfect it work... Thank you so much..Kevin..I really appreciate it..YOur the best dude..Thanks again